# Python Pandas - Inserir itens de lista em ordem numa coluna

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Esse é o tipo de dúvida que fica difícil até de explicar, mas vamos tentar.

Segue o código:

```
data = {"Id": ["01", "02", "03", "04",'05'],"Fruta": ['bananaAAA','bananaBBB','bananaCCC','bananaDDD','bananaEEE']}
base_dados = pd.DataFrame(data)
display(base_Dados)

    Id  Fruta
0   01  bananaAAA
1   02  bananaBBB
2   03  bananaCCC
3   04  bananaDDD
4   05  bananaEEE
```

Esta é o dataframe, como vocês podem ver, depois de toda "banana" possui um tipo de codigo, exemplo: AAA, BBB, CCC... Pois bem, eu peguei apenas apenas esses pontos desses itens no codigo abaixo.

```
for fruta in base_dados['Fruta']:
    fruta = fruta[6:9]
    print(fruta)

AAA
BBB
CCC
DDD
EEE
```

Até ai tudo bem, mas eu gostaria de inserir uma nova coluna no dataframe(base_dados) com essas informações da string, como no código abaixo

```
base_dados.insert(2, 'tipo', fruta)
display(base_dados)
    Id  Fruta   tipo
0   01  bananaAAA   EEE
1   02  bananaBBB   EEE
2   03  bananaCCC   EEE
3   04  bananaDDD   EEE
4   05  bananaEEE   EEE
```

Porém como foi visto, os itens não são inseridos **em ordem**.
Eis um exemplo de como eu queria:

```
    Id  Fruta   tipo
0   01  bananaAAA   AAA
1   02  bananaBBB   BBB
2   03  bananaCCC   CCC
3   04  bananaDDD   DDD
4   05  bananaEEE   EEE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para fazer isto você deve criar outra coluna no `datraframe` e utilizar o método `.apply()` para aplicar uma fórmula para cada linha.

O código para criar a coluna de "tipo" fica assim:

```
base_dados['tipo'] = base_dados['Fruta'].apply(lambda x: x[6:9])
```

Resultado:

|  | Id | Fruta | tipo |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 01 | bananaAAA | AAA |
| 1 | 02 | bananaBBB | BBB |
| 2 | 03 | bananaCCC | CCC |
| 3 | 04 | bananaDDD | DDD |
| 4 | 05 | bananaEEE | EEE |

O seu erro aconteceu porque você estava redefinindo a variável `fruta` e aplicando novamente para todas as colunas.

Comment: Já é a segunda vez hoje Felipe! Obrigado pela atenção. Então, acredito que o caminho seja por ai mesmo, quando eu fiz no meu projeto real que é o do meu trabalho(evito postar com os dados da empresa), devolve o seguinte resultado: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
Então decidi colocar o .loc... mas ai retornou o seguinte resultado: "None of [Index(['500', '195'], dtype='object')] are in the [index]" 
500 e 195 são os resultados que eu quero inserir.

Comment: https://ibb.co/mFmtW3K segue como resulta

Comment: Olá, Bruno, é um prazer ajudá-lo. Tente assim: `mtx['AH'] = list(map(lambda x: x[11:14],mtx['Descricao'])))`. No meu teste não da o mesmo erro que você encontra.

Comment: Deu certo felipe, Obrigado! Eu criei um novo dataframe em cima do base_dados, segui o artigo: https://paulovasconcellos.com.br/o-que-%C3%A9-a-value-is-trying-to-be-set-on-a-copy-of-a-slice-from-a-dataframe-e85f744d8be1